# ¿Cómo puedo compactar mi código usando querySelectorAll en JavaScript en vez de llamar por id?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Cómo puedo **simplificar mi código** usando el QuerySelectorAll si cuando lo uso me da error.

Tengo este **montón de llamadas por id** pero no estoy seguro si hay un camino mejor para hacer lo mismo:

```js
   sidebar.querySelector('#lista').classList.toggle("mover-items");
   sidebar.querySelector('#text-hidden').classList.toggle('hidden');
   sidebar.querySelector('#icon').classList.toggle('mx-2');

   sidebar.querySelector('#lista2').classList.toggle("mover-items");
   sidebar.querySelector('#text-hidden2').classList.toggle('hidden');
   sidebar.querySelector('#icon2').classList.toggle('mx-2');

   sidebar.querySelector('#lista3').classList.toggle("mover-items");
   sidebar.querySelector('#text-hidden3').classList.toggle('hidden');
   sidebar.querySelector('#icon3').classList.toggle('mx-2');

   sidebar.querySelector('#lista4').classList.toggle("mover-items");
   sidebar.querySelector('#text-hidden4').classList.toggle('hidden');
   sidebar.querySelector('#icon4').classList.toggle('mx-2');

   sidebar.querySelector('#lista5').classList.toggle("mover-items");
   sidebar.querySelector('#text-hidden5').classList.toggle('hidden');
   sidebar.querySelector('#icon5').classList.toggle('mx-2');
```

Y tengo esta otra forma que **me da error** (todavía no la paso por un for por dicho problema):

```js
   sidebar.querySelectorAll('list').classList.toggle("mover-items");
```

Mas este otro método me da error en consola "***Uncaught TypeError:** Cannot read property 'toggle*' of undefined", pero no tengo idea de **por qué** me dice esto, puede que esté pasando algo obvio por alto porque no soy tan bueno con JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es causado porque intentas usar `querySelectorAll` de un modo similar a `querySelector`, pero lo que estos dos métodos devuelven es distinto:

- `querySelector(<filtro>)` devuelve el primer elemento que pase el filtro.
- `querySelectorAll(<filtro>)` devuelve **una lista** de elementos que cumplen con la condición.

Por tanto, podrías marcar los elementos que quieras agrupar con una clase y luego recorrer la lista resultante, algo como:

```
sidebar.querySelectorAll(<filtro>).forEach(elem => elem.classList.toggle("mover-items"));
```

Comment: Me funcionó tu respuesta de lujo! Le faltaba el paréntesis del elemt pero listo eso fue todo! Gracias buen hombre

Comment: Sí, faltaba un paréntesis al final y `elemt` debía ser `elem`. ¡Corregido! Me alegra que la respuesta te sirva

Answer (score 1):

Si te referis a hacerlo mas corto, creo que esa es tu pregunta, hay una forma.
Dentro del objeto window esta el document, y dentro todos los id que escribas en tu codigo, si en vez de poner document.querySelector('#lista'), en su lugar pones algo asi:

```
lista.classList.toggle('mover-items');
```

Ya que podes acceder directo a su id, como si fuera un objeto.

Por cierto, no te funciona con las clases el identificador, porque no las estas definiendo correctamente.

Con document.querySelectorAll se escribe asi:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.nombre-de-clase'); //Te estas olvidando el "."
```